# What part of the following function make it asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dom

I'm learning javaScript and just came on the topic of promises , async await , fetch etc.
While reading a tutorial online , It described the following code as **asynchronous**

```
function loadScript(src) {
let script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = src;
document.head.append(script);
}
```

I have learned that javascript hands over all the asynchronous work to the browser , like http request as they take time and might block the flow in javascript.

Please point out to me how the above code is asynchronous?
Which part of it is asynchronous? Is it because we are using document object?
are all methods in document object asynchronous and handled by the browser?
or is it something else?

here is the link to the tutorial, sorry if I misunderstood something.https://javascript.info/callbacks

Comment: Please link the tutorial that made this claim. No, there is no asynchronous method anywhere.

Comment: What would *make* the code asynchronous is to install a `load` handler on the `script` element, as that callback would be invoked asynchronously.

Comment: Added the link to the description.

Comment: Ah. Well, that page explains it quite well actually, did you read on? "*The script is executed “asynchronously”, as it starts loading now, but runs later, when the function has already finished*". It's not about `loadScript` itself being asynchronous, it's about starting an asynchronous action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asynchronous because you're fetching the script code from the server, using the `src` URL. That has to send a network request, and the code won't be inserted into the DOM and executed until the server responds.

Modifying the DOM itself is synchronous, but a number of elements can cause network requests to be sent and wait. Examples are `<script>`, `<img>`, and `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 1):

The script tag itself needs to load the url so this is the part that is asynchronous. Scriptloads are handled by the Browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the fact that dynamically created `script` elements behave as though they have their `async` attribute set, that's outlined [in the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#script-processing-model):

> A script element has a flag indicating whether the element will be "non-blocking". Initially, script elements must have this flag set. It is unset by the HTML parser and the XML parser on script elements they insert. In addition, whenever a script element whose "non-blocking" flag is set has an async content attribute added, the element's "non-blocking" flag must be unset.

...but even if the script element doesn't have `async` set, the download of the source code is still going to happen asynchronously; `async` simply says "don't block further HTML parsing or JavaScript execution while waiting for this to download." The code that injects the script will still finish running, but any subsequent script elements on the page will wait for blocking scripts to download.